# Sound card configuration problem in EndeavourOS

Tags: audio, endeavouros

I am a beginner Linux user. I have purchased a new internal sound card creative and would like to set it as the default in the system. I don't know how to do it:

```
[me@pc ~]$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x4202110000 irq 165
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xa1080000 irq 17
 2 [Creative       ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Creative
                      HDA Creative at 0xa1b04000 irq 16
 3 [Audio          ]: USB-Audio - LCS USB Audio
                      Solid State System Co.,Ltd. LCS USB Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-11, full speed
 4 [WEBCAM         ]: USB-Audio - C270 HD WEBCAM
                      C270 HD WEBCAM at usb-0000:00:14.0-6, high speed
[me@pc ~]$
```

On Windows 10/11, after installation, there is no sound because the card immediately switches to speaker mode instead of headphones. The same thing happens in Linux. I have to go to the terminal, use the alsamixer command, select the Creative card, and unmute "Front" because it's muted every time I restart the computer. I want to set this Creative card as the default and fix the muting of "Front" so there is sound every time the system starts up.

Comment: What sound server are you using ? (pulseaudio ? pipewire ?) (it is likely that these interfere with alsamixer settings.)